# Pandas: apply operation with generated list is not callable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large DataFrame that looks consists of a list of game titles, which often contain their console.

```
    title
1 Nier Automata (ps4) 
2 Halo 5  Xbox One
```

I want to automatically assign it to a new column, category, which contains the names of the console.

```
      title               category
1 Nier Automata (PS4)        PS4
2 Halo 5  Xbox One           Xbox One
```

I thought this would be a perfect fit for an .apply operation and wrote the following code:

```
console_list = ['PS4', 'Xbox One', 'PC', 'PS3', 'PS2', 'Xbox 360', '3DS']
df['category'] = df['title'].apply(lambda x: y for y in console_list if y in x)
```

It throws the following error:

```
  File "scraper.py", line 153, in <module>
    df['auto_categorie'] = df['titel'].apply(lambda x: y for y in console_list if y in x)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2551, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx", line 1521, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable
```

But I though I was not calling the list object itself, but its contents (y), that anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need `list comprehension`:

```
df['category'] = df['title'].apply(lambda x: list([y for y in console_list if y in x]))
```

Another solution with [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html):

```
df['category'] = df['title'].str.findall('|'.join(console_list))
print (df)
                 title    category
1  Nier Automata (PS4)       [PS4]
2      Halo 5 Xbox One  [Xbox One]
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to case inconsistency I would suggest you to use `upper()`:

```
df['category'] = df['title'].apply(lambda x: list([y for y in console_list if y.upper() in x.upper()]))
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion that saves me a lot of difficulty in the future, thanks!